# Get current time in Unix Timestamp Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, unix-timestamp

How can I get current time in Unix Timestamp format in kotlin as integer?

Comment: val currentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()

Answer (score 9):

If you're using Kotlin on the JVM or Android, it's as simple as

```kotlin
val unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
```

for the unix time in milliseconds, or

```kotlin
val unixTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000
```

for the unix time in seconds (rounded down).